# Geting PARSE ERROR: error while access the csv file by Apache drill

Tags: apache, apache-drill

Getting parser error while accessing the csv file by Apache Drill.

CSV file already present in hdfs. location =/metatest

The apache drill query to fetch the data from csv file.

```
select * from hdfs.'metaview/CSAT_Score.csv'
```

hdfs storage already created in apache drill:

```
  {
      "type": "file",
      "enabled": true,
      "connection": "hdfs://XXx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/", --removed the actual path
      "workspaces": {
      "root": {
       "location": "/",
       "writable": true,
       "defaultInputFormat": null
     },
      "metaview": {
        "location": "/metatest",
        "writable": true,
        "defaultInputFormat": null
     }
   },
   "formats": {
     "csv": {
       "type": "text",
       "extensions": [
        "csv"
       ],
        "skipFirstLine": true,
        "delimiter": ","
     }
   }
 }
```

while running the sql in apache drill its giving

```
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ". \'/u01/HomeDir/dssbp/Manoranjan/CSAT_Score.csv\'" at line 1, column 19. Was expecting one of: "ORDER" ... "LIMIT" ... "OFFSET" ... "FETCH" ... "NATURAL" ... "JOIN" ... "INNER" ... "LEFT" ... "RIGHT" ... "FULL" ... "CROSS" ... "," ... "EXTEND" ... "(" ... "." ... "AS" ... ... ... ... ... ... "TABLESAMPLE" ... "WHERE" ... "GROUP" ... "HAVING" ... "WINDOW" ... "UNION" ... "INTERSECT" ... "EXCEPT" ... "." ... "." ... "." ... "." ... "." ... "." "*" ... "[" ... while parsing SQL query: select * from hdfs.'/u01/HomeDir/dssbp/Manoranjan/CSAT_Score.csv' ^ [Error Id: dde43d82-fb14-410b-8f48-8115c17169c8 on INBBRDSSVM328.india.tcs.com:31010] (org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException) Encountered ". \'/u01/HomeDir/dssbp/Manoranjan/CSAT_Score.csv\'" at line 1, column 19. Was expecting one of: "ORDER" ... "LIMIT" ... "OFFSET" ... "FETCH" ... "NATURAL" ... "JOIN" ... "INNER" ... "LEFT" ... "RIGHT" ... "FULL" ... "CROSS" ... "," ... "EXTEND" ... "(" ... "." ... "AS" ... ... ... ... ... ... "TABLESAMPLE" ... "WHERE" ... "GROUP" ... "HAVING" ... "WINDOW" ... "UNION" ... "INTERSECT" ... "EXCEPT" ... "." ... "." ... "." ... "." ... "." ... "." "*" ... "[" ... org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.convertException():391 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.normalizeException():121 org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmt():149 org.apache.calcite.prepare.PlannerImpl.parse():168 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan():162 org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL():924 org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run():250 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1142 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():617 java.lang.Thread.run():745 Caused By (org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.ParseException) Encountered ". \'/u01/HomeDir/dssbp/Manoranjan/CSAT_Score.csv\'" at line 1, column 19. Was expecting one of: "ORDER" ... "LIMIT" ... "OFFSET" ... "FETCH" ... "NATURA`enter code here`L" ... "JOIN" ... "INNER" ... "LEFT" ... "RIGHT" ... "FULL" ... "CROSS" ... "," ... "EXTEND" ... "(" ... "." ... "AS" ... ... ... ... ... ... "TABLESAMPLE" ... "WHERE" ... "GROUP" ... "HAVING" ... "WINDOW" ... "UNION" ... "INTERSECT" ...
```

Comment: Did this  work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from hdfs.metaview.`CSAT_Score.csv`
```

If you have multiple files in this workspace, you can use:

```
use hdfs.metaview
select * from `CSAT_Score.csv`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,should work..

select * from dfs.`/metatest/CSAT_Score.csv`  //provided u have given cluster info in ur storage plug in.

Here it seems issue with single quote and a slash at the start of ur file,u have to use quote present with negation symbol.